# javascript property race condition

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I have a phonegap project on iPhone and Android. The issue appears to be a race condition on the surface, but I don't understand how it happens. Users are able to click on a button which has a closure callback that sets a property of an object, and then clears the screen and loads the main menu. In code:

```
button.onclick = function (employee) {
    return function () {
        employee.task = "some task";
        returnToMenu();
    }
}(employees[i]);
```

After the user is back on the main menu, they can click on a button that loads a screen which displays all the users. If an employee has that task property set, additionally formatting should be done to the button for that employee.

```
if (employee.task)
    // style the button being created for this employee
```

Somehow, if one clicks fast enough, the formatting is not done. If you click back (to the main menu), and reload the screen, the formatting is now done. Given the code above, I do not see how `employee.task` could possibly return undefined after the menu has been loaded.  What's going on here?

Comment: Can you recreate the problem in jsfiddle? It's hard to know what's up here with only the code shown. Also, use the JS `debugger` and `console.log()` to investigate and see what values things have at key points. What does `employee` look like right before `if (employee.task)`?

Comment: I'm unable to recreate the problem on the phones I have. I was working with the end users earlier today and they were able to reproduce it several times. That's part of why this has been so difficult to debug.